# how to read and display data fro a table in grails

Tags: oracle, grails

I have an oracle database and I want to display data from a particular table (class) to my Grails application. I am just looking for the procedure.

thank you.
this what I have

### DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true

    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    username = "hr"
    password = "Destiny"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1524:orcldata"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1524:orcldata"
        }
    }
}
```

### portfolio.groovy

```
package all

class Portfolio {
    int classid
    String classname     
    int capacity

    static constraints = {

        classid()
        classname()
        capacity()      
    }
    static mapping ={
        table : 'class'

        version false
        columns{
            classid column:'classid'    
            classname column:'classname'    
            capacity column:'capacity'    
        }


    }
}
```

And after executing I got this error:

```
2016-02-26 15:17:20,553 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
```

Comment: What do you have so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks like Hibernate was unable drop the objects in your development database. I'd start by ensuring that the hr account has enough rights to DROP objects. Note: Unless you narrow down the scope of this question, it's probably going to get closed (and obliterated).

Comment: Try to manually drop all tables from your db and check if after restart of app the error is still there.